# What wire-brushs can be used at 28000 rpm

Tags: powertools, replacement, bit

I have a hand me down [Weller Mini-Shop power tool](https://www.ebay.com/itm/184945515145?mkevt=1&mkcid=1&mkrid=711-53200-19255-0&campid=5338722076&toolid=10001) and I finally used up the wire brush that came with it (I was removing glue from an aluminum frame). Looking online I see a lot of wire brushes that state maximum rpm 20k or less but the specs of my tool says that its equipped with a 28k rpm motor. Most reviews of wire brush say that their brushes don't last long and I suspect its because of people exceeding maximum rpm (I 90% sure I just finished doing the same).

Now that I'm looking for a replacement I want to know what I should be looking for when I'm picking out a new wire brush so that it can survive 28k rpm. I've looked at [Dewalt Wire-brushes](https://www.dewalt.com/products/accessories/abrasives/wire-brushes) and the max rpm that Dewalt has is for 22k rpm.

Comment: So buy from Weller, they must sell wire brushes rated for their drills. Or are you going to come back with "they are too expensive"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I take it by the fact that you linked to an eBay item that Weller quit the rotary tool business.   Okay then.  Fortunately, they were competing with the [**Dremel**](https://us.dremel.com/en_US/tools/-/subcategory/tool/find-by-category/27343/rotary), which is basically the "household name" for that type of tool.

I bet yours is equivalent with a 1/8” arbor and similar speeds. (You can test that by putting a 1/8” drill bit in it, if it chucks up happily it is Dremel compatible).   **So look for Dremel accessories.** You won't have any trouble finding those.

I realize you went to eBay because nobody else had a listing, *not* because you'd shop there.  But for the record eBay, Amazon, Banggood, AliExpress, wish.com etc. are no place to buy rotary tools.  Safety is everything. You only have two eyes.

The items you linked from DeWalt are enormous by comparison. The smallest ones are intended to be put on much larger full size drills or die grinders. The largest are made for big 1/3 horsepower angle grinders.  If you attempted to use any of them on a Dremel-like, it would stall instantly when the bristles touch the work.

Answer (score 2):

Dremel tools are high quality and go up to 35000 rpm. I would get their wire brushes which are available in many sizes, shapes and materials.

Answer (score 1):

What to look for:

It will have a firm attachment to the tool, and the number of RPM will be 28000 or higher.

Tools for these mini die grinders tend to have 1/8" shank or 1/8" hole so ignore the quarter inch ones, they are for full size die grinders.